# JavaScript Function Queue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ton of functions that need to run in succession, but not before the other has completed. What I need is a way to queue these functions to run only after the previous function was successfully completed. Any Ideas?

```
Function1();
Function2();
Function3();
Function4();
Function5();
```

Comment: Your code should work just fine ... (if by "sucessfully completed" you mean that the function returned)

Comment: Is there async stuff in your functions? If not, I can't see a problem.

Comment: Most of my functions contain AJAX calls. And each one depends on a success from the previous call.

Comment: You may look in to playing with [deferring calls](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) (as of jQuery 1.5). They probably have a way of writing plugins that bind to the success/failure events so it drops right in to jQuery's environment.

Comment: Nice comment on jQuery deferreds. I've use them in Twisted before but didn't know they were in the new jQuery.

Answer (score 8):

You could use something like this:

```
var FunctionQueue = (function(){
    var queue = [];
    var add = function(fnc){
        queue.push(fnc);
    };
    var goNext = function(){
        var fnc = queue.shift();
        fnc();
    };
    return {
        add:add,
        goNext:goNext
    };
}());
```

and use it like this:

```
var fnc1 = function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        alert("1 done");
        FunctionQueue.goNext();
    }, 1000);
};

var fnc2 = function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        alert("2 done");
        FunctionQueue.goNext();
    }, 5000);
};

var fnc3 = function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        alert("3 done");
        FunctionQueue.goNext();
    }, 2000);
};

FunctionQueue.add(fnc1);
FunctionQueue.add(fnc2);
FunctionQueue.add(fnc3);
FunctionQueue.goNext();
```

Edit after a few years:
Another way people are approaching this is to pass in a `next` function that you can call to continue the chain. Like so:

```
var Queue = function(arr){
    var index = 0;
    var next = function(){
        if (index >= arr.length) {return;}
        arr[index++](next);
    };
    return next;
};

var fn1 = function(next){
    console.log("I am FN1");
    next();
};

var fn2 = function(next){
    console.log("I am FN2");
    setTimeout(next,1000);
};

var fn3 = function(next){
    console.log("I am FN3");
    setTimeout(next,3000);
};

var fn4 = function(next){
    console.log("I am FN4");
    setTimeout(next,1000);
};

Queue([fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4])();
```

Answer (score 5):

You could create a Queue function:

```
function Queue(arr) {
    var i = 0;
    this.callNext = function() { 
        typeof arr[i] == 'function' && arr[i++]();
    };
}
```

So if these were your functions...

```
function f1() {
    alert(1);   
}

function f2() {
    alert(2);   
}

function f3() {
    alert(3);   
}
```

... you just pass them (their references) inside a new Queue instance:

```
var queue = new Queue([f1, f2, f3]);
```

Then you execute `callNext()` to call the functions sequentially:

```
queue.callNext();
queue.callNext();
queue.callNext();
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/CEdPS/3/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do exactly as you have shown, by listing them in a covering function?

```
function do_1_to_5() {
    Function1(); 
    Function2(); 
    Function3(); 
    Function4(); 
    Function5();
}
```

If your function contains AJAX calls, then you need to hook them up at the end of the callback functions that handle the AJAX calls.

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing, putting the next function in the success callback of jquery's $.ajax call. I just thought there may have been a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure they run consecutively, you might return a value from each one and use that returned value in the subsequent one...

```
function do_1_to_5() {

    r1 = Function1(); 
    r2 = Function2(r1); 
    r3 = Function3(r2); 
    r4 = Function4(r3); 
    r5 = Function5(r4);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all that machinery, just put your functions in an array. Then you can loop over them.

```
var runThese = [
    Function1,
    Function2, 
    Function3,
    Function4,
    Function5
];
```

JavaScript is single-threaded so you're guaranteed one finishes before the next starts.

```
for (var i = 0; i < runThese.length; i++) {
    runThese[i]();
}
```

Or since your functions have deterministic names, you could avoid the array altogether:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    window["Function" + String(i)]();
}
```

Comment: Didn't see the comment that each function needs to wait for something async on the previous function. So this isn't what you need after all. Can't really answer the question properly without knowing the content of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out async.js - it provides a mechanism for chaining up functions so they execute asynchronously or one after another, with an excellent way to catch the results and/or errors from all the executed functions.

https://github.com/caolan/async