# Javascript functions queue

Tags: javascript, function, queue

I am writing an application in Javascript and JQuery and I need to follow a sequential order on functions calls, so I've thought in using a queue. 
I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952788/javascript-function-queue), but (if is possible) I would prefer abstract or avoid function(next) in my function calls like example below because I have a lot of custom functions:

```
var fn1 = function(next){
    console.log("I am FN1");
    next();
};
```

Is it possible or there are another alternative and I don't know it?

Answer (score 0):

None of this is tested, but...
You could set up an array of functions and iterate through them:

```
var fn1 = function(){ code here };
var fn2 = function(){ code here };
var functionQueue = [ fn1, fn2 ];
$.each(function(functionQueue, functionItem){ functionItem(); });
```

or, if you specifically wanted to have a 'next()' function, you could do:

```
var fn1 = function(){ code here };
var fn2 = function(){ code here };
var functionIndex 0;
var functionQueue = [ fn1, fn2 ];
var next = function(){ functionQueue[functionIndex++]() }
```

Comment: Thanks, @K3N. I haven't worked out how to format code like that in SO [blush]

Comment: no problem! :) Everything isn't always obvious. Here is a link that can be useful for other things as well: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help Just add four spaces in front, or, mark the block and hit ctrl+k

Answer (score 0):

There must be various options.

One might use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) and its [waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) function:

> ```
> async.waterfall([
>     function firstFunction(callback1) {
>         callback1(null, 'one', 'two');
>     },
>     function thisIsCallback1(arg1, arg2, callback2) {
>       // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
>         callback2(null, 'three');
>     },
>     function thisIsCallback2(arg1, lastCallback) {
>         // arg1 now equals 'three'
>         lastCallback(null, 'done');
>     }
> ], function (err, result) {
>     // result now equals 'done'
>     // If the first argument of any function defin in the array
>     // is not falsy, this, function will be invoked and
>     // err will have its value
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Since functions are first class objects, you can add them in an array and then use the Array.shift function to call them one by one (for a First-In-First-Out approach) :

```
//define your functions
function fn1(){...}
function fn2(){...}

//create an array to store your function into
var functionQueue = [];

//push the functions into the array
functionQueue.push(fn1);
functionQueue.push(fn2);

//loop through the array, each time calling the first function
while(functionQueue.length > 0){
   (functionQueue.shift())();
}
```

I hope this helps!