# JavaScript - updating a page on a timer

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout

I am a information technology teacher at a high school, teaching students to code through JavaScript (this is the best language for my particular environment - distance education).

I have written a maze navigation script in order to teach students sequential and iterative coding techniques. The students use two commands, move or turn left to navigate a maze - the maze is displayed in a table on the page.

I want my script to show the progress of the maze navigation to the students, so that they can more easily identify their errors and correct them. Do do this, I have used the setTimeout() to wait every time the function which re-draws the table is called. the problem is that the browser waits until all of the commands are run and processed, before showing the final result. This means that students can't see their progress.

The only way that I have been able to get it to work, is to replace the setTimeout() with an alert(), this pops up an alert for every "step" in the program - I don't like this solution.

I have done a lot of research on this, most articles I have found seem to include some sort of busy loop, but this does not work for me as the browser will just wait for the busy loop to finish before displaying the result.

Is this possible? Can I get my code to show each iteration of the program?

Here is my maze object (the showMaze() function is what I have been working on):

```js
/*****************************
** Maze Game                **
*****************************/

"use strict";


// Create the maze object
var Maze = {
    //Object global variables
    char: { x: 1, y: 1 },
    direction: "N",
    speed: 1000,
    maze: [],
    err: "",
    target: "dispArea",
    timerID: "",
    stepCnt: 0,

    //Set up the default maze
    defaultMaze: function ()
    {
        var imaze = []
        imaze[0] = ["#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"];
        imaze[1] = ["#", "X", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"];
        imaze[2] = ["#", " ", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"];
        imaze[3] = ["#", " ", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", " ", " ", " ", "#", " ", " ", " ", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"];
        imaze[4] = ["#", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "#", " ", " ", "#", "#", "#", " ", " ", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"];
        imaze[5] = ["#", "#", "#", "#", "#", " ", "#", " ", " ", "#", "#", "#", " ", " ", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"];
        imaze[6] = ["#", "#", "#", "#", "#", " ", "#", "E", " ", "#", " ", " ", " ", " ", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"];
        imaze[7] = ["#", "#", "#", "#", " ", " ", "#", "#", "#", "#", " ", " ", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"];
        imaze[8] = ["#", "#", "#", "#", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"];
        imaze[9] = ["#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#", "#"];
        return imaze;
    },

    //Draw the maze on the screen
    drawMaze: function ()
    {
        var output = "<table>";
        document.getElementById(Maze.target).innerHTML = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            output += "<tr>";
            for (var x = 0; x < 20; x++)
            {
                output += "<td>" + Maze.maze[i][x] + "</td>";
            }
            output += "</tr>";
        }
        output += "</table>";
        output += "Direction: " + Maze.direction + "<br>";
        output += "Character position: " + Maze.char.x + ", " + Maze.char.y + "<br>";
        output += Maze.err + "<br>";
        document.getElementById(Maze.target).innerHTML = output;
        clearTimeout(this.timerID);
    },

    showMaze: function ()
    {
        //This doesn't work
        this.timerID = setTimeout(this.drawMaze, this.speed);
        //The below does work
        /*is.drawMaze();
        alert("Step: " + this.stepCnt);
        this.stepCnt++;*/
    },

    blankChar: function (x, y)
    {
        this.maze[y][x] = " ";
    },

    addChar: function (x, y)
    {
        this.maze[y][x] = "X";
    },

    move: function ()
    {
        if (this.direction == "N")
        {
            if (this.checkLocation(this.char.x, (this.char.y - 1)))
            {
                this.blankChar(this.char.x, this.char.y);
                this.char.y -= 1;
                if (this.checkWin(this.char.x, this.char.y))
                {
                    this.addChar(this.char.x, this.char.y);
                    this.win();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.addChar(this.char.x, this.char.y);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.err = "-------Error: That's a wall.--------";
            }
        }
        else if (this.direction == "S")
        {
            if (this.checkLocation(this.char.x, (this.char.y + 1)))
            {
                this.blankChar(this.char.x, this.char.y);
                this.char.y += 1;
                if (this.checkWin(this.char.x, this.char.y))
                {
                    this.addChar(this.char.x, this.char.y);
                    this.win();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.addChar(this.char.x, this.char.y);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.err = "-------Error: That's a wall.--------";
            }
        }
        else if (this.direction == "E")
        {
            if (this.checkLocation((this.char.x - 1), this.char.y))
            {
                this.blankChar(this.char.x, this.char.y);
                this.char.x -= 1;
                if (this.checkWin(this.char.x, this.char.y))
                {
                    this.addChar(this.char.x, this.char.y);
                    this.win();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.addChar(this.char.x, this.char.y);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.err = "-------Error: That's a wall.--------";
            }
        }
        else if (this.direction == "W")
        {
            if (this.checkLocation((this.char.x + 1), this.char.y))
            {
                this.blankChar(this.char.x, this.char.y);
                this.char.x += 1;
                if (this.checkWin(this.char.x, this.char.y))
                {
                    this.addChar(this.char.x, this.char.y);
                    this.win();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.addChar(this.char.x, this.char.y);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.err = "-------Error: That's a wall.--------";
            }
        }
        this.showMaze();
    },

    checkLocation: function (x, y)
    {
        if (this.maze[y][x] == "#")
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    },

    checkWin: function (x, y)
    {
        if (this.maze[y][x] == "E")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    },

    win: function ()
    {
        this.showMaze();
        alert("Congratulations, you got to the end of the maze!");
        return;
    },

    turnLeft: function ()
    {
        if (this.direction == "N")
        {
            this.direction = "E";
        }
        else if (this.direction == "E")
        {
            this.direction = "S";
        }
        else if (this.direction == "S")
        {
            this.direction = "W";
        }
        else
        {
            this.direction = "N";
        }
        this.showMaze();
    },

    init: function ()
    {
        this.maze = this.defaultMaze();
        this.showMaze();
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Maze game!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dispArea">Test</div>
        <script>
            Maze.init();
            Maze.turnLeft();
            Maze.turnLeft();
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Maze.move();
            }
            Maze.turnLeft();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Plz  ,learn about jQuery for DOM handling as well as Bootstrap for UI

Comment: I have used jQuery and Bootstrap a bit, but not for this kind of application. Is there a specific function in jQuery you are referring to? I have seen the .delay() function, but I am not sure how to apply that to one of my functions, instead of to a DOM element.

Comment: I tried fiddling with your code but couldn't get it working right. You could do something with a custom queue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952788/javascript-function-queue or you could look into Promises in javascript where the promises would resolve after X seconds.